# Questions regarding the processing of mosaic Landsat 8

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, landsat, mosaic, digital-image-processing

**Approximate Translation of Original Question:**

A question of theoretical and practical about the mosaic of satellite images. I have 3 different months of Landsat images, which need to accomplish the end MaxVer classification. At what point should I make the mosaic of 3 scenes? before or after sorting? Follow the steps ...

Acquisition >> Georeferencing >> Atmospheric Correction >> Classification >> Mosaic

or

Acquisition >> Georeferencing >> Atmospheric Correction >> Mosaic >> Classification

**Original Question:**

Uma dúvida de ordem teórica e prática a respeito do mosaico de imagens orbitais. Possuo 3 imagens Landsat de meses distintos, a qual necessito realizar ao final uma classificação MaxVer. Em que momento devo realizar o mosaico das 3 cenas? antes ou depois da classificação? Segue as etapas...

Aquisição>>Georeferenciamento>>Correção atmosférica>>Classificação MaxVer>>Mosaico

ou

Aquisição>>Georeferenciamento>>Correção atmosférica>>Mosaico>>Classificação MaxVer

Comment: please ask in English

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be two camps about this one.  Some prefer to mosaic before classification, others prefer to classify the images before mossaicking.  Personally, I would classify the images first, then mosaic them.

Have a look at the discussions on [this page](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/sci/Satellite-Imagery-FAQ/part3/section-14.html) and you'll find arguments for and against both methods.  Generally, they state that you should classify first, then mosaic.

Try both options and see which gives you the best results.